# How to confirm whether I am running in a RDP mstsc /admin session?

Tags: remote-desktop, rdp, windows-server-2019

**Inside** an already started RDP session how would I confirm whether I am indeed running inside a session successfully started with the admin switch (`mstsc /admin`)?

I think with older server versions you could see if the Session ID for the session was 0 (zero) but it does not seem that way anymore.

Rephrasing the question would be; Where or how **inside** the RDP sessions would I compare a session started with the `/admin` switch and one started without it to see which is which?

Answer (score 1):

Try to test the SystemInformation.TerminalServerSession property (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.terminalserversession).

Create a PowerShell session and run the following commands:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation]::TerminalServerSession
```

Comment: This only indicates whether you are in a Terminal Server Session and not whether the session was started with the /admin switch or not